# How to extract the first number of a data in mysql?

Tags: mysql, regex

for example,

I have a dataset as below:

```
asdf1234asdf
1235asdfasdf
asdfasdfef489
```

How could I select such that I can get a result as below?

```
1234
1235
489
```

Comment: seems like a simple case of (\d+)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your MySQL version supports it, [create a function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-procedure.html) and use such as regex, to extract the first digits:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION first_digits(str TEXT)
  RETURNS TEXT
BEGIN
  DECLARE ret TEXT DEFAULT '';
  DECLARE chr TEXT DEFAULT '';
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
  WHILE i < (LENGTH(str) + 1) DO
    SET chr = SUBSTRING(str, i, 1);
    IF chr REGEXP '[0-9]'
      THEN SET ret = CONCAT(ret, chr);
    ELSEIF ret != ''
      THEN RETURN ret;
    END IF;
    SET i = i + 1;
  END WHILE;
  RETURN ret;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then just `SELECT` desired column with newly created function `first_digits();`

```
SELECT first_digits('asdf1234asdf') num;

num
1234
```

To extract all digits (not only first), drop the `ELSEIF` part and rename the function such as `digits`.

To drop the function:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS first_digits;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL, unfortunately, doesn't have a good way of replacing regexes, but if you have only one numerical sequence, you could use [`trim`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim):

```
SELECT TRIM(BOTH 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' FROM word) 
FROM (SELECT 'asdf1234asdf' AS word
      UNION ALL
      SELECT '1235asdfasdf'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'asdfasdfef489') t
```